# Errors in .NET 6 Hello World console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, console-application

After following the steps from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0) for setting up a new Console Application in **.NET 6.0**, I immediately get syntax errors from Intellisense. However, when I do `dotnet run`, the program runs as expected. *weird*

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the **folder**, **sample code** and **terminal**

[image]

- `Program`: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [HelloWorld]
- `Void`: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported [HelloWorld]
- `string`: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [HelloWorld]
- `Console`: The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context [HelloWorld]

**.NET SDKs installed**

- 5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
- 6.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

**HelloWorld.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Relevant VS Code Extensions:**

1. C# v1.24.0

Comment: Can you try to restart vscode and try it again?

Comment: Don't show images of code in question! Copy and paste the code, much easier for us (we might want to copy some of the code in an answer.

Comment: @PoulBak I understand it's frowned upon but decided to post the screenshot anyway.  It seemed useful for the situation.  I will add the code, also.

Comment: I have many questions:  following that tutorial with .NET 6 should result in a Program.cs with a top-level statement template, really just 1 comment. and one console.writeline.  So please confirm the .NET version in your CSPROJ file.

Also, VSCode should have prompted you to install the C# (OmniSharp) extension. please confirm your visual studio code extensions related to C#.

Comment: @AdamVincent Not sure what you mean by "top-level statement template".  I updated the post with the information you requested.

Comment: Remove bin and obj and rebuild.

Comment: Omnisharp is just not functioning to the level that we should expect, it's so very brittle that it crashes and fails to do anything way too often. But the immediate cause for most problems right now as far as I can tell, is the Implicit Usings. You'll want to disable that for now. I too was having issues and omnisharp was not updating the state of the editor like it usually does, until I disabled implicit usings then updated my source files. I can't tell for sure if this fixes all problems, but this was the big one that was breaking it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, worked when i deleted the ".vs" hidden folder. this folder was in the same location of ".sln" file

Answer (score -1):

Deleting .vs worked for me.

Problem seemed to start after an MS Windows (10 pro) update.

Problem also accompanied by a VS 2022 (17.2.6) recoverable exception when trying to display a project properties (see below).

For all its worth, when rebuilding all projects in the solution (12 of them) compile with no errors and the code runs just fine - yet the editor shows tons of errors (but not in all files or projects - weird).

Call stack for the exception:

## =====================
7/20/2022 11:31:27 AM
Recoverable
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecutionException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.ProjectSystemShim.EntryPointFinder.FindEntryPoints(INamespaceSymbol symbol)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.StartupObjectsEnumGenerator.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageDynamicEnumProperty.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.SupportedValueDataProducer.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.QueryDataFromProviderStateProducerBase`1.<SendRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Start>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<InitializeAsync>d__10.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertiesEditor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.AsyncLoadContent.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()